# why `history.go(-1)` does not work after close the fancyBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i added a `<a>` tag in my page which refers to the jQuery `fancybox()`:

```
<a class='iframe' href="someLink">sth</a>
<input type="button" value=".." onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"/>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
         type: 'iframe',
         showCloseButton: false,
         'hideOnOverlayClick':true
    });
});
```

the painful problem is: after i click the `.iframe` and then close the fancybox, the page cannot goback to the previous one immediately. i need to click twice!
yes, it is in chrome browser. but it works well in FX.
what is wrong with it?!

Comment: Drop the javascript:, that is useless. Than go back two `history.go(-2)`

Comment: no, no. my codes works badly in chrome only. it's normal in IE and firefox. use `-2` as parameter will cause problem in these browsers.